# Extract multiple binds at once

Tags: sql, oracle, database-performance, awr

I just found i can use extract_binds to get binds-info from raw bind data (like the one in v$sql, dba_hist_sqlstat etc)

```
select
    listagg(value_string, ',') within group (order by position)
from
    table(dbms_sqltune.extract_binds(raw_bind_data))
```

When i have to get info on many many raw bind-data, can i avoid running this in a loop ? Can i pass more than one raw bind to this function ? Should i use union-all or is there a better way ? (Better in terms of time taken, efficiency..)

Thanks,
Trinity

Comment: Not sure quite what you're trying to achieve, but have you had a look at [DBA_HIST_SQLBIND](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_4050.htm#REFRN23446) ?

Comment: Yes, but i have a set of sql_id - (raw) bind_data pairs, with no snap_id.